# beaglebone : name resolution does not give same address as my PC

Tags: linux, dns, beagleboneblack, nslookup

I have a beaglebone rev A6b (uname -a : "Linux beaglebone 3.2.34 #1 Wed Nov 21 14:17:11 CET 2012 armv7l GNU/Linux") connected to the Internet. My beaglebone and my PC are behind the same L2 switch (and then same LAN).

```
nslookup feeds.angstrom-distribution.org 8.8.8.8
```

On beaglebone :

```
Name:   feeds.angstrom-distribution.org
Address 1: 140.211.169.179 feeds.angstrom-distribution.org
```

On PC :

```
Name:   feeds.angstrom-distribution.org
Address: 140.211.169.161
```

**Address are different, why ?**
note that ping 140.211.169.179  fails .... (so no update possible on my beaglebone...).

Comment: The DNS entry you mention has a TTL of 300 seconds, i.e. 5 minutes - maybe its owner had simply changed it inbetween your two lookups?

Comment: In fact, whenever I do the experiment, I always get different results on my beaglebone vs my PC. I even tried on another PC connected to WLAN, but still, I find the same ip address as the PC on LAN. I was wondering whether there is a name caching on beaglebone, and whether I can flush this cache.

Comment: ...and amazingly, for the time being, I see this issue only with the site feeds.angstrom-distribution.org. With other site, I get same IP address on my beaglebone or my PC....

Comment: Just to make sure, do you have another DNS client on the device that you can use to verify your `nslookup` isn't somehow causing it? Try `host` or `dig`.

Comment: unfortunately, nor host, nor dig are available.